# Android GridView getColumnWith in API 15 (android 4.0)

Tags: android, gridview

I need GridView.getColumnWith() in API 15 which is not supported in android API less than 16.

I searched but I did not found solution.

Comment: A suggestion is get GridView width and divide the column count (of course subtract the paddings between column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
private int getTheWidth(){
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    return mGridView.getColumnWidth();
else {
    try {
    Field mField = GridView.class.getDeclaredField("mColumnWidth");
    mField.setAccessible(true);
    Integer wid = (Integer) field.get(this);
    field.setAccessible(false);

    return wid.intValue();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it before but it did not solved my problem in this case my gridview cropped and shown in half of screen.

Comment: I used this solution once and it worked fine for me. Why not find the width of element inside gridView and work out from there.

Comment: oh It worked for me too I had used this in a wrong way.I fix it and it works.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
int columWidth = gridView.getWidth() / gridView.getNumColumns();
```

Worked like a charm, but may be approximative (do not take borders into account).